# Panels + Taxonomy Terms + URL Path

Tags: views

Ok, I am struggling with this one a bit so I am going to describe this in the most simplest of forms.

I run a Drupal 7 website that is a holiday resort guide for Magaluf. The site lists in detail all things relating to the resort; ie. Hotels, Bars, Restaurants, Event Tickets etc.

I am now expanding into other resorts. I am playing around in the correct way to go.

So, I have a node type - Restaurant. When I create a new node - restaurant I have many fields. 2 of these fields are taxonomy terms to tag the restaurant in the right way. They are:

[taxonomy-term:resort] & [taxonomy-term:cuisine]

Say I create a new restaurant, for example 'Joes Fish and Chips' that is based in the resort 'Magaluf'. When creating the node, I will tag this restaurant by 1st selecting the term [Magaluf] in the [field_resort], as well as selecting multiple [taxonomy-term:cuisine] term's for the field_cuisine.

So now, I have my restaurant.

I have set up a url path for all restaurant nodes as follows

resort/[field_resort]/restaurant-guide/[node-title]

---

I have just started to play around with panels. I have created a panel page where it displays a list of all the restaurants in teaser display based on contextual filters from 2 arguments.

The contextual filter arguement: resort/%1/restaurant-guide/%2

%1 = [taxonomy-term:resort]
%2 = [taxonomy-term:cuisine]

So, if you type in the url www.domain.co.uk/resorts/magaluf/restaurant-guide/fish you will get a list of all the restaurants in 'Magaluf' that have been tagged with 'Fish'

---

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO.

I would like a way to display all the [taxonomy-term:cuisine] in a pane on another panel page which is;

www.domain.co.uk/resorts/magaluf/restaurant-guide

The taxonomy terms will be listed and the url's for each term should have the arguments of the panel page .Once you click on one of those terms, this then takes you to the panel page argument for that specific resort; ie;

clicking on FISH on the domain www.domain.co.uk/resorts/ZANTE/restaurant-guide will now take you to www.domain.co.uk/resorts/ZANTE/restaurant-guide/FISH

clicking on MEAT on the domain www.domain.co.uk/resorts/IBIZA/restaurant-guide will now take you to www.domain.co.uk/resorts/IBIZA/restaurant-guide/IBIZA

Hope you understand.